# javascript json : create new json using value of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

Below is my input

```
input= 

    [{
            "CalendarDate": "2019-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "SLA": 0.01,
            "ContractBasedFlag": "Y",
            "name": "A"
        },
        {
            "CalendarDate": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "SLA": 0.02,
            "ContractBasedFlag": "Y",
            "name": "B"
        },
        {
            "CalendarDate": "2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "SLA": 0.03,
            "ContractBasedFlag": "Y",
            "name": "C"
        }
    ]
```

Now if we look into this input, i need to create a new json by splitting the value of "CalendarDate" and using the whole value of "SLA".

```
output= 

    [{
        "201910": 0.01
    }, {
        "201911": 0.02
    }, {
        "201912": 0.03
    }]
```

I'm trying to use reduce() function on input to get it but still facing some issue.

Comment: Have you tried a simple loop?

Comment: reduce is also more or less like using for. it takes one element at a time and then we can process that element.

Comment: Your wanted output makes no sense at all.

Comment: @user3205921: sure, but a loop makes it more explicit, removing one complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```js
const ret = [{
    CalendarDate: '2019-10-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    SLA: 0.01,
    ContractBasedFlag: 'Y',
    name: 'A',
  },
  {
    CalendarDate: '2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    SLA: 0.02,
    ContractBasedFlag: 'Y',
    name: 'B',
  },
  {
    CalendarDate: '2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    SLA: 0.03,
    ContractBasedFlag: 'Y',
    name: 'C',
  }
].map(x => ({
  [`${x.CalendarDate.split('-')[0]}${x.CalendarDate.split('-')[1]}`]: x.SLA,
}));

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to loop thru the array. Use `substring` to cut a string and use `replace` to replace the string.

```js
var input = [{"CalendarDate":"2019-10-01T00:00:00.000Z","SLA":0.01,"ContractBasedFlag":"Y","name":"A"},{"CalendarDate":"2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z","SLA":0.02,"ContractBasedFlag":"Y","name":"B"},{"CalendarDate":"2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z","SLA":0.03,"ContractBasedFlag":"Y","name":"C"}];

var result = input.map(o => ({[o.CalendarDate.substring(0, 7).replace("-", "")]: o.SLA}))

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)